# Choose a specific fingerprint to be used for authentication

Tags: java, android

I have an Android project that interacts with fingerprints. The user wishes that the application can only be opened with certain fingerprints.

For example, say that on the device there are 2 fingerprints, `fingerprint-1` and `fingerprint-2`. So when opening the application, the user can only use `fingerprint-2` to unlock it. How can this be done? I have not found a solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible on Android with the built-in fingerprint scanner.  By design, there is no API to differentiate between the specific fingerprints, as they are all considered to belong to the same user.

If you wanted to do this, you'd need an extra peripheral fingerprint scanner to connect to the device that allows you to differentiate between fingerprints.